# How to make the iframe block requests from certain domains?

Tags: html, iframe

Is there an attribute for iframes that will make it block requests to certain domains? Something like the following:

```
<iframe src="www.example.com" block-domains="google.com"></iframe>
```

So if `block-domains` is that magical attribute I'm looking for, it's telling the iframe to block all requests to `google.com`.

Comment: A bit of background on why you want this might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest you can get to this is by setting X-Frame-options in the HEADER declaration. The documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) states that you can provide any one of the 2 following options (the 3rd being obsolete):

- *DENY :* the iframe will not be displayed, regardless of the page trying to embedd it
- *SAMEORIGIN :* the iframe will only be displayed if called by a site having the same origin as the page itself (by checking the frame ancestors)

Another work around might be to use [frame-ancestors](https://content-security-policy.com/frame-ancestors/#:%7E:text=An%20Example%20frame%2Dancestors%20Policy,being%20framed%20by%20other%20pages.&text=Using%20frame%2Dancestors%20%27none%27,a%20frame%20or%20iframe%20tag.) as part of content security policy header, that will allow you to specify sites on which the iframe can be embedded.

Comment: I think the question is about the parent blocking what can be in the iFrame, not the iFrame blocking what sites it can be contained in.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible unless you have access to set response headers of the domain you want to load.

If you have access then you can set [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) response header to `frame-src`. It restricts what domains a page can load in an iframe.

**For example:** If the website at `https://example.com` has a response header of
`Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self' *.trusted.com`. Then it is only possible to make requests to `example.com` and `*.trusted.com` domains inside iframe.